# CodeIgniter 4 problema al instalar con composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Tengo problemas al intentar instalar CodeIgniter 4 via Composer, en un servidor local (xampp)

El codigo que me tira es el siguiente:

```
    PS C:\Users\PuercoRico> cd D:\xampp\htdocs
PS D:\xampp\htdocs> composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter ci4 -s rc
Installing codeigniter4/appstarter (4.0.0-rc.4)
  - Installing codeigniter4/appstarter (4.0.0-rc.4): Loading from cache
Created project in ci4
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.2.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework 4.0.0-rc.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for codeigniter4/framework ^4@rc -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0-rc.4, v4.0.0-rc.1, v4.0.0-rc.2, v4.0.0-rc.2.1, v4.0.0-rc.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - D:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

La versión de php que me encuentro utilizando es la 7.4.1

Alguna idea de que puede ser el error o como puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: Como te recomienda el mismo mensaje de *error*, verifica si en tu **php.ini** todas esas extensiones estan habilitadas, deberían estar sin el símbolo de `#` al inicio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Busca en tu archivo **C:/xampp/php/php.ini** lo siguiente, y quita el punto y coma **( ; )**:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

Esto debería activar la extensión faltante que es requerida por composer.

*Recuerda reiniciar xampp una vez guardado el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, pero en el archivo php.ini no había la línea:

;extension=php_intl.dll

Entonces, agregué dicha línea, reinicié XAMPP, y funcionó.
Mi versión de XAMPP es 7.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo y tampoco tenía la línea:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

Pero en cambio tenía la misma línea sin **.dll**:

```
;extension=php_intl
```

Le quité el ";" para des-comentarla y funcionó perfectamente.