# Cómo corregir el error The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: intl

Tags: macos, codeigniter-4

XAMPP - 7.4.1-1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODEIGNITER 4

pero me sale el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien habilite:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero nada, al parecer no esta

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [CodeIgniter 4 problema al instalar con composer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329790/codeigniter-4-problema-al-instalar-con-composer)

Comment: @RafaelBautista no en mac es diferente, hice lo que dice pero nada

Comment: Necesitas agregar la ubicación de la carpeta de PHP a las variables de entorno del sistema operativo y en el php.ini agregar la ruta de la carpeta de extensiones.